qbittorrent and Mullvad in Docker wont work
So I installed ubuntu 22.04 on a machine and Docker afterwards. Then I installed Portainer.
I tried to setup qbittorrent and mullvad both as container but they don't work. I checked the logs of both of them and I don't get any error messages. I tried to following command in the qbittorrent console in portainer :
curl -sS https://ipinfo.io/json
I tried it to check, if the qbittorrent container uses the mullvad container as network interface but i get following error message:
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: ipinfo.io
Following are the configuration files for mullvad and qbittorrent:
version: "3"
services:
  gluetun:
    image: qmcgaw/gluetun
    container_name: mllvd    
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
    ports: #make sure to include these for qbittorrent to work
      - 6081:6881
      - 6081:6881/udp
      - 6011:6011      
    environment:
      - VPN_SERVICE_PROVIDER=mullvad
      - VPN_TYPE=wireguard
      - WIREGUARD_PRIVATE_KEY=****************
      - WIREGUARD_ADDRESSES=***********
      - SERVER_CITIES=Zurich
    volumes:
      - /Home/Docker/Gluetun:/gluetun
    restart: unless-stopped

qbittorrent:
---
version: "2.1"
services:
  qbittorrent:
    image: ghcr.io/linuxserver/qbittorrent
    container_name: qbittorrent
    environment:
      - PUID=1000
      - PGID=1000
      - TZ=Europe/Madrid
      - WEBUI_PORT=6011
    volumes:
      - /home/Docker/qbittorrent/config:/config
      - /home/Downloads:/downloads
    network_mode: "container:mllvd" #change gluetun to your VPN container name   
    #network_mode: "service:your_gluetun_service_name" #change gluetun to your VPN service name  
    # ports: #you wont need the ports in this configuration file, you will need to include them in the Gluetun container
    #   - 6081:6881
    #   - 6081:6881/udp
    #   - 6011:6011  
    restart: unless-stopped

Thanks for any help


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
